# TikZ failing to draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I'm trying to use TikZ to make flow charts in my LaTeX files, but I'm getting an error.  Here's the LaTeX I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Some text
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=2.5cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!50, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=2.5cm, minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2, node distance = 2cm, auto]
\node [block] (init) {initialize model};
\node [cloud, left of=init] (expert) {expert};
\node [cloud, right of=init] (system) {system};
\node [block, below of=init] (identify) {identify candidate models};
\node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models};
\node [block, left of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (update) {update model};
\node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {is best candidate better?};
\node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {stop};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I literally copied-and-pasted this code from [an example document](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/), just to use as a test.  And here's the error it produces:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ellipse' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Well, I didn't misspell it.  I get a similar error message for the diamond as well.  How can I fix this?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should have worked more carefully. You have forgotten to include the `tikZ` libraries.

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
```

It would have been easier to download the source file instead of copy&paste.

Comment: Although, to be fair, the example does present it's self as being "complete" with `\documentaclass`, `\includepackage`, etc.  Looks like it needs some updating to reflect the modularization of TikZ.

Comment: @Sharpie: The original example does have the right `\usetikzlibrary` command.  So this _was_ a cut-and-paste error.

Comment: Why yes it does.  A failure on my part to actually follow the texample link and double check the asker's example.

Comment: I fell into this with a simple `\node[draw,ellipse]`. The manual mentions `ellipse` from p153 on without any note about having to load a library; in fact, it says on p1030, "The package [shapes] is loaded automatically by pgf". Well, apparently it is not. (This is on Tex Live 2014, TikZ/PGF 3.0.0.)